# Android Toolbar TextView match_parent getting bigger than screen

Tags: android, layout, center, toolbar

I have a Toolbar with a TextView inside with `match_parent` to center the text but every time I do so it gets bigger than the screen and hides the text.

**Here you have a capture of it running**

[image]

**How this looks like in the preview**

[image]

And finally how I implement it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:theme="@style/ToolBarStyle" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/title_activity_anuncios" />

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check your theme on style or set activity theme from the manifest

```
 android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
```

If activity theme is correct then you can check your activity >> onCreate method.

```
   ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    if (actionBar != null) {
        actionBar.setTitle("Your Title");
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, I totally forgot about that

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your toolbar

```
app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
```